# Print every URL visited in the console

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, umijs

I'm taking over a web application written by someone else in React+Node+Express+Redux+Umi. I'm new to React+Redux+UMI.

It is not a web site that we could see Url in a web browser. But I can use Chrome Dev Tools for debugging. I want to insert some code to the frontend, so that each time the URL (before redirection and after redirection) of the visited pages is printed in the console. Does anyone know where I could insert the code to this React application?

Comment: What kind of router does it have? Is it `react-router`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not a web site where you can see the url?

Comment: Thats a bit of a broad question. But I guess you could stick it anywhere that gets called when your page loads.

Comment: Yes, it is `react-router`.

Comment: It is a JavaScript Excel add-in written in web technologies. But when we run it, we cannot see the URL.

Comment: @putvande I don't see what you mean. I don't want to add `console.log(window.location.href)` to every page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your top level app component you can use one of react-routers hooks to do this.

```
function App() {

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(`route change: ${location.pathname}`);
  }, [location.pathname]);

}
```